# DataStax C# Driver: how to create table with mapping of IEnumerable to set?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I want to use the Table.CreateIfNotExists() to create my schema dynamically, but I can't figure out how to make it create a "set" column type for an IEnumerable instead of "list".

Is this possible without using CQL statements to create the table?

```
For<ClassWithSet>()
            .TableName("withset")
            .PartitionKey(u => u.Id)
            .Column(u => u.SomeStrings, cm => cm.WithName("somestrings").WithDbType<IEnumerable<string>>());

var table = new Table<ClassWithSet>(session);
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `SortedSet<T>` as db type:

```
For<ClassWithSet>()
            .TableName("withset")
            .PartitionKey(u => u.Id)
            .Column(u => u.SomeStrings, 
                cm => cm.WithName("somestrings").WithDbType<SortedSet<string>>());

var table = new Table<ClassWithSet>(session);
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```